# Validación de objetos Java en spring sin anotaciones

Tags: java, validación

Estoy usando `MyBatis` para todas las acciones que implican la interacción con la base de datos. También estoy trabajando con Angularjs para el *frontend*, así que las validaciones en el cliente se hacen con `angular-validation-ghiscoding` y con validaciones nativas de html5. Me gustaría validar los datos también en el *bankend*, pero sin usar anotaciones.

Acá hay un ejemplo del código:

```
@RequestMapping(value = SecureApiResources.URI_UPDATE_ACCOUNT, method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
    public @ResponseBody Account updateAccount(
            @RequestBody final AccountRequestUpdate accountRequest) { // Object to be validated (accountRequest)

        Account account = accountMapper.getAccountOfMerchant(authContextHolder.getMerchantId(), authContextHolder.getDefaultAccountId());

        if (account == null) {
            HttpErrors httpErrors = new HttpErrors(
                    SecureApiResources.ERROR_ACCOUNTS_NOT_FOUND);
            throw new EntityNotFoundException(httpErrors);
        }
        int resultUpdate;
        try {
            // In this point I should validate the accountRequest object
            account.setAccountName(accountRequest.getAccountName());
            account.setCommercialName(accountRequest.getCommerciaName());
            account.setCountry(accountRequest.getCountry());
            account.setCity(accountRequest.getCity());
            resultUpdate = accountMapper.updateMerchant(account);
            if (resultUpdate == 0) {
                HttpErrors httpErrors = new HttpErrors(
                        SecureApiResources.ERROR_ACCOUNTS_NOT_FOUND);
                throw new EntityNotFoundException(httpErrors);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            HttpErrors httpErrors = new HttpErrors(
                    SecureApiResources.ERROR_SQL_NOT_EXECUTE);
            throw new EntityNotFoundException(httpErrors);
        }

        return account;
    }
```

En la misma clase tengo un método para crear una cuenta y recibo otro objeto de modelo (`AccountRequestCreate accountRequest`).

¿Cuál puede ser la mejor opción a implementar sin utilizar xml ni anotaciones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no quieres usar ni XML ni anotaciones tienes 2 opciones:

- crear una clase de utilería
- dotar a tus clases de setters validadores

---

## Clase de utilleria:

Cuando uso esta tecnica, creo a la vez una excepcion personalizada para controlar todos los errores posible y devolver el mensaje localizado en caso de aplicaciones internacionalizadas:

```
public class MyValidator {

    public static void validateAccountRequest(AccountRequestUpdate accountRequest) 
        throws MyI18NException 
    {
        // aqui validas los campos necesarios
    } 
}
```

La excepcion tiene que ser algo asi:

```
public class MyI18NException extends Throwable implements Serializable {
    public MyI18NException (String errorMsg) {
        // traducimos el codigo de error 
        String localizedMessage = datasource.get(errorMsg);
        // acciones propias
        super(localizedMessage);
    }
}
```

Y para usarlo:

```
try {
    // In this point I should validate the accountRequest object
    MyValidator.validateAccountRequest(accountRequest);
    account.setAccountName(accountRequest.getAccountName());
    account.setCommercialName(accountRequest.getCommerciaName());
    account.setCountry(accountRequest.getCountry());
    account.setCity(accountRequest.getCity());
    resultUpdate = accountMapper.updateMerchant(account);
    if (resultUpdate == 0) {
        HttpErrors httpErrors = new HttpErrors(
                SecureApiResources.ERROR_ACCOUNTS_NOT_FOUND);
        throw new EntityNotFoundException(httpErrors);
    }
} catch (MyI18NException e) {
    // maneja el error como necesites
} catch (Exception e) {
    HttpErrors httpErrors = new HttpErrors(
            SecureApiResources.ERROR_SQL_NOT_EXECUTE);
    throw new EntityNotFoundException(httpErrors);
}
```

## Setters validadores:

Aunque esta opcion te la recomiendo menos, puedes aprovechar las asignaciones a los atributos de `Account` para validar los datos que te vienen del *front* son correctos creando `setters` que devuelvan `boolean` o tiren excepciones:

**NOTA:** este caso solo sirve si no persistes `AccountRequestUpdate` directamente sino que usas los datos para crear otros objetos.

**Validando:**

```
public boolean setAttribute(String attribute) {
   if(Utils.notNullOrEmpty(attribute) && attribute.contains("cadena_obligatoria")) {
       this.attribute = attribute;
       return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

**Tirando excepción:**

```
public void setAttribute(String attribute) throws MyI18NException {
   if(Utils.notNullOrEmpty(attribute) && attribute.contains("cadena_obligatoria")) {
       this.attribute = attribute;
   } else {
       throw new MyI18NException("Empty.String");
   }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Una buena idea es usar la interfaz Validator de Spring, anotarlo como Component (bean de spring) así puedes inyectarlo y utilizarla cuando la necesites, por una parte es limpio y por otra, está en concordancia con las librerías de Spring Framework.

Un ejemplo de implementación es el siguiente:

```
public class UserLoginValidator implements Validator {

    private static final int MINIMUM_PASSWORD_LENGTH = 6;

    public boolean supports(Class clazz) {
       return UserLogin.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
    }

    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
       ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "userName", "field.required");
       ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "password", "field.required");
       UserLogin login = (UserLogin) target;
       if (login.getPassword() != null
             && login.getPassword().trim().length() < MINIMUM_PASSWORD_LENGTH) {
          errors.rejectValue("password", "field.min.length",
                new Object[]{Integer.valueOf(MINIMUM_PASSWORD_LENGTH)},
                "The password must be at least [" + MINIMUM_PASSWORD_LENGTH + "] characters in length.");
       }
    }
 }
```

Puedes encontar más información en los siguientes enlacs:

- Documentación oficial de Spring de los diferentes tipos de validaciones que proponen, como ves se encuentra el ejemplo que te propongo: [enlace](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html).
- Pequeña guía con ejemplos de como implementar un validator y utilizarlo: [enlace](http://fruzenshtein.com/spring-mvc-validator-initbinder/)